# how to access usb drive through internet using a aspx application in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, usb, remote-access

I have to make an aspx webform application that will detect an USB of a machine when it logs in into the website and the usb will be accessable from another machine which also logged in to the website ...
is this possible? if yes then how i can achieve this?

Comment: Not possible directly through .NET (over the internet). Your confusion is the difference between server-side and client-side. Your .NET code will be running server-side.. not client side in a WebForms application. You could look into building a client-side ActiveX control or perhaps Silverlight (not sure what security there is on Silverlight). Maybe there's another way to achieve what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: the need is we have customers who have usb drives with some data now we need to update that data time to time so we are trying to solve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's possible, it violates pretty much everything I've ever learned about web browser security sandboxing.

About the only way I can think you'd possibly be able to do something like this would be through the creation of a browser plugin, where the user would specify things on a browser-by-browser basis.

What is the business case for needing this kind of communication? Maybe there's another way to do what you're trying to do, that would be workable within the realm of web browser security restrictions.

Comment: the need is we have customers who have usb drives with some data now we need to update that data time to time so we are trying to solve this

Comment: @Drone Why does it have to be a WebForms application? Will a WinForms application not be sufficient?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead i am not that sure how i will do that in winform? any suggestion ?

Comment: Well.. firstly, your WinForms application will have direct access to the USB.. a WebForms application won't.. at all. Your WinForms app has the ability to access both the local computer and a remote server for updates.. something a WebForms application will not be able to do. That is now a separate question since you'll be switching from WebForms to WinForms..

Comment: ok yess .. ok let me talk to the clients .. i am not sure if they have access to common server .. but thanks for the help

Comment: If you have an IIS server to host a webapp, that could act as your common server. A winforms app can download data over http.

Answer (score 0):

I had previously able to reach a COM port using an ActiveX object and authorizing it via Caspol (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb6t8dtz(v=vs.80).aspx) on client machines in .NET 2.0.

Howwever things had been changed from then and this may not be possible in newer versions of .NET. Also this will give you a big headache. Go with WinForms if possible.